# Using JavaScript, how can I reset all the select's in my form so that the first option for each is selected?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form containing only select fields, a submit button and a reset button.

```
<form id="search_form">

<select id="country">
  <option value="-1">Select Country</option>
  <option value="22">USA</option>
  <option value="23">Germany</option>
  ...
</select>

<select id="regions">
  <option value="-1">Select Region</option>
  ...
</select>

<input type="reset" value="Reset />

</form>
```

Each of the select fields has a default option with a value of "-1".

When a user clicks on the reset button, I want all the selects to show the option with this "-1" value as being selected.

What is the best way to do this using JQuery?

Comment: ? The reset button already does exactly that, without any scripting help.

Comment: @bobince - It doesn't do that, it resets the values to what they were onload, not quite the same in cases of edits.

Comment: `<input type="reset">` resets the value to the `defaultValue`/`defaultChecked`/`defaultSelected` properties, which are the values of the value/checked/selected attributes in the HTML. (If no option has a selected attribute, it behaves as if the first option did.) It doesn't reset to the onload values, which may be different to the HTML values in the case of form value memory. In the above markup `reset` will set both selects to `-1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just make a single [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) call, like this:

```
$("#search_form select").val("-1");
```

Or the entire handler:

```
$("#search_form input:reset").click(function(e) {
  $(this).closest("form").find("select").val("-1");
  e.preventDefault();
});​
```

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/VxpGP/), though if you're just using this to default the values instead of resetting them, I'd use a button instead of a `type="reset"`.